# Difference between ssh manually and in a script

Tags: ssh

I am using AIX. I am trying to open PVCS (a Serena application) which is present in a Linux server. If I manually ssh to Linux server, set DISPLAY variable and invoke PVCS it works properly. However if I try ssh, set DISPLAY variable and invoke PVCS in a shell script, not all functionalities is working. I am receiving segmentation faults. As it is working directly on the Linux server, we did not get much help from Serena.

Could someone help me? What could be the issue?

```
#!/bin/ksh
#test.sh
if [[ $HOSTNAME != linux-server ]]
then    
   ssh linux-server test.sh $DISPLAY
   exit 0
fi

if [[ $# == 1 ]]
then
    export DISPLAY=$1
fi

#invoke pvcsexecutable
/serena/vm/linux/bin/pvcsvmux

exit 0
```

If the above script is invoked from the AIX server, it opens PVCS but some of the functionality is not working. However, if I ssh into the Linux-server and run this, it works without any problem.

Comment: Can you post that script?

Comment: did you export the DISPLAY variable into the script?

Comment: yes. I exported. I added the code we are using.

Comment: So, if you ssh to the linux box and run that script INSIDE the linux box, it does work?

Comment: yes it works without any issues.

Comment: Try adding `. ~/.bashrc` after #test.sh line (mind the dot space it is important). One thing, are you sure you are using ksh in the linux box? if it is then you should change .bashrc for .profile

Comment: By the way, you are calling test.sh which is a script that must be created in your linux box's user home with a variable (DISPLAY) that has not been initialized, so you are calling test.sh without parameters.

Comment: One more difference I noticed is, if I manually ssh, .profile is executed and all variables are set. But the same is not setup in script.

Comment: if you call it within the script as I pointed it will, you will need the dot space ~/.profile as I stated in the previous comment. Plus the DISPLAY variable uninitialized.

Comment: I tried but it still not works.

Comment: What value are you passing as DISPLAY? Try to debug with `bash -x` and insert a `set` to see what variables you have defined in your linux box when you run your script through `ssh`...